# Rcpp - store dataframe row reference matching two criteria to use in for loop

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp

I am following up on an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148923/calculations-on-each-row-of-a-data-table-in-r) in which I was looking for a more efficient way in R to calculate variables in row `i` using other values in `i` *and* `i-1`. The suggestion from Andy Baxter was to investigate Rcpp, along with a tremendous starter block of code. A week later and I have made some tremendous progress along these lines, and Rcpp is showing excellent promise for my problem.

A fairly trivial step in R has me stalled in Rcpp, which is storing a dataframe/data.table row number for use in calculations.

Using the following example data.table:

```
stands <- data.table(ID=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),timestep=rep((1:3),3),parent_ID=c(rep(NA,6),"A",rep(NA,2)),parent_timestep=c(rep(NA,6),2,rep(NA,2)),A=round(runif(9),2),B=c(1.5,NA,NA,2.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),C=c(9.2,NA,NA,8.7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

   ID timestep parent_ID parent_timestep    A   B   C
1:  A        1      <NA>              NA 0.59 1.5 9.2
2:  A        2      <NA>              NA 0.43  NA  NA
3:  A        3      <NA>              NA 0.74  NA  NA
4:  B        1      <NA>              NA 0.81 2.5 8.7
5:  B        2      <NA>              NA 0.95  NA  NA
6:  B        3      <NA>              NA 0.94  NA  NA
7:  C        1         A               2 0.81  NA  NA
8:  C        2      <NA>              NA 0.99  NA  NA
9:  C        3      <NA>              NA 0.92  NA  NA
```

Within a for loop (in Rcpp), I seek to fill the `NA`s by calculations using values in the same row, and the row before. This part is simple, e.g., calculating stands[2,"B"] might refer to stands[2,"A"] and stands[1,"B"] - I have this part working in my Rcpp code.

However, sometimes I need to refer to values in a row matching a specific ID and timestep, e.g., the missing values in stands[7,"B"] and stands[7,"C"]. For the sake of this example, let's say they need to be calculated based on values held in stands[2]. I have a mechanism for determining which row the values are held in, but don't know how to look up these values from the dataframe in Rcpp.

My Rcpp code is fairly simple and I'm sure the solution for this is simple as well, but I would like to look up the correct row then store the row (or vector) number as a variable so I can subset other rows (or vectors) for subsequent calculations within a for loop.

Using data.table, I would use:

```
parent_ID <- stands$parent_ID[i]
parent_timestep <- stands$parent_timestep[i]
j <- stands[ID == parent_ID & timestep == parent_timestep, which = TRUE]
```

This would set `j` to 2, and then I could simply pass `j` within my for loop to make calculations on that row when conditional statements point the loop to using that particular code, e.g.

```
i <- 7
stands$B[i] <- stands$A[i] * stands$B[j]
```

I have looked pretty thoroughly through SO posts and cannot find the answer I am looking for. It may be out there, but I am not experienced enough yet in Rcpp to understand how answers to similar problems might be applied in this setting.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me with this!

EDIT to add:
My Rcpp code is as follows:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
  
  //[[Rcpp::export]]
  DataFrame calcs(DataFrame df) {
   CharacterVector ID = df["ID"];
   NumericVector timestep = df["timestep"];
   CharacterVector parent_ID = df["parent_ID"];
   NumericVector parent_timestep = df["parent_timestep"];
   NumericVector A = df["A"];
   NumericVector B = df["B"];
   NumericVector C = df["C"];
 
int n = ID.size();

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
  if(timestep[i] == 1) {
    continue;} // skip timestep == 1 - these values are already in the table

  if(parent_timestep[i] > 0){ 
//this will be the case when calculations require lookups
    
...//this is the part that I an unsure of
   
   } else { 
   //if no inheritance condition is set
     
     ...//carry out normal calculations using [i] and [i-1] as usual
```

This additional information and code was requested by a user. Thank you!

Comment: There's a lot of detail in your post that seems irrelevant to your specific question. Is this what you're asking: "I would like to store the row (or vector) number as a variable so I can subset other rows (or vectors) for subsequent calculations within a for loop." If so, can you make a very small example to demonstrate it?

Comment: @tospig this is close, and I agree some simplification would probably help clarity, but I need the for loop to find the appropriate row/vector number by searching for the row that matches two criteria, as demonstrated above. I provided the example of the R code to demonstrate how I would do it with data.table, wondering how that translates into Rcpp.

Comment: " I have a mechanism for determining which row the values are held in" & "My Rcpp code is fairly simple" can we see these?

Comment: @tospig see the edits in the question for more. Thanks!